# Cyrillic characters from javascript cookie to php output via $_COOKIE

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

When i'm trying to put russian text in cookie via javascript and then output it via php it returns:

%u043F%u0440%u043E%u0432%u0435%u0440%u043A%u0430

How to decode this to normal cyrillic characters?

This is the function i'm using to pass to document.cookie:

```
function setCookie(c_name,val,c_expiredays,c_path,c_domain,c_secure)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+c_expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(val)+

    /* Additional settings */
```

((c_path) ? "; path=" + c_path : "") +
((c_domain) ? "; domain=" + c_domain : "") + // used to allow using only on a certain domain
((c_secure) ? "; secure" : "") + // used for HTTPS (SSL)

```
    ((c_expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}
```

setCookie('name',$(this).val(),1);

On server side, i'm outputting like that:

```
(isset($_COOKIE['img_href_value']) ? $_COOKIE['img_href_value'] : '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put non-ASCII characters directly in a cookie (what happens if you try varies over each different browser and many of them mangles the results irretrievably).

So you have to choose some encoding to use to use on cookie values. It doesn't matter what, as long as your client-side JavaScript and server-side PHP agree on one encoding. URL-encoding is certainly a popular choice of encoding scheme for this purpose, but it's not mandated by any standard and tools won't automatically decode it for you.

- To get characters out of a URL-encoded cookie value you must manually call `rawurldecode` on the value at the PHP end, or `decodeURIComponent` to extract from `document.cookie` at the JavaScript end.
- To encode to this format the corresponding functions are `rawurlencode` on the PHP side and `encodeURIComponent` in JavaScript.
- (This assumes you are using UTF-8 for your strings, which you should be.)

**Don't** use `urlencode` for this in PHP (it's for form submission parameters only and gets the space character wrong in this context), and **definitely don't** use `escape` in JavaScript (it gets every non-ASCII character wrong, coming up with that weird non-standard `%uNNNN` format you quoted).

(In general, JS `escape`/`unescape` is an ancient and highly questionable encoding scheme that you should almost never have any reason to use.)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Encode-JavaScript-Cyrillic/Encode/JavaScript/Cyrillic.pm.html

Comment: link no longer works

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20100412194200/https://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Encode-JavaScript-Cyrillic/Encode/JavaScript/Cyrillic.pm.html